# Get the latest record of each item of a list (QUERY) - Apex Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

Given a list, I would like to get the latest People__c from each item on personList.
It is possible with a single query?

```
List<People__c> listPeople = [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM CombinedAttachments 
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM People__c WHERE Person__c IN :personList];
```